# Iball Modem's LAN port as WAN port

Tags: lan, wan

My modem is 150M Wireless-N ADSL2 + Router

Model No.: iB-WRA150N
 with firmware :2.0.0 Build 120626 Rel.13023.
In this device there are 4 LAN ports(RJ45) and 1(RJ11) port for telephone cable.

THERE IS NO WAN PORT WITH RJ45.

I want to connect the internet cable with RJ45.
How can I do this? Is there any way to convert any LAN port to WAN port? Is the device need firmware update?

Answer (score 1):

So your device is an **ADSL router**, not a modem.

It can be used only to connect to ADSL networks, so there is no way to use it any other cases. Also it can't be used as a simple switch.

You need to ask your ISP (internet service provider) to learn what type device you need to connect to the internet.